# Determinant with full rank or rank deficient matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Let $X$ be an $n \times p$ matrix with $\text{rank}(X) \le p$. Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ positive definite matrix.

When $\text{rank}(X) =p$, $X$ is of full rank, and $|X'AX|>0$ should hold. Similarly, when $\text{rank}(X) < p$, $|X'AX|=0$ should hold. However, I don't know how to prove these statements.

Also, I'm wondering if $|X'AX|>0$ implies that $\text{rank}(X) = p$ and if $|X'AX|=0$ implies that $\text{rank}(X) < p$.

Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: unless $n=p$, $X'AX$ is not defined. Did you mean $XAX'$?

Comment: Sorry, $A$ is $n \times n$, not $p \times p$.

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your original post for the next reader